# Convert JS to Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a simple Javascript app that counts duplicate numbers inside of an array...

I am currently learning Typescript and I would like to turn this Javascript into a Typescript...

I have angular up and running on my machine, but it can get overwhelming when learning everything about Angular 2.0 and Typescript at the same time.

What would be the best way to convert this to a Typescript?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
  console.log(n);

  var counts = {};
  n.forEach(function(x) {
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
  });

  document.write(
    "<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>" +
      "<p>You entered following numbers:</p>" +
      n +
      "<br/>" +
      "<p>The occurence is as follows:</p>" +
      JSON.stringify(counts)
  );
});
```

Comment: Any javascript file is also  valid typescript. So you're sort of already done

Comment: If you're having trouble learning angular and typescript at the same time (and it's totally reasonable that you would) then **don't**. Work through some typescript tutorials. Get used to thinking in types. Then learn angular.

Comment: Yeah, I am following typescript course on pluralsight and it's great, however if a newbie has a question it can be tough to find an answer by just googling (typescript is not as widespread as Javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool to convert JavaScript files to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't have to do anything, your JS would work fine in TS as well. But if you want to take advantage of all features this is how it would look:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    var n = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
    console.log(n);

    var counts : { [nr: string]: number } = {};
    n.forEach((x) => { 
        counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) +1; 
    });

    document.write(`
    <h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>
    <p>You entered following numbers:</p>${n}<br/>
    <p>The occurence is as follows:</p>${JSON.stringify(counts)}`);

});
```